# How can I run a while loop in the background so that the other operations can continue (Python)

Tags: python, loops, concurrency

I am making a simple game, and have created a loop to continuously check if the enemy is dead:

```
while player_health > 0:
    if current_enemy_dic['current_enemy']['Health'] <= 0:
        slayed_enemy_count = slayed_enemy_count + 1
        enemy_encounter(slayed_enemy_count)
```

The problem is that the program will not allow the other code to run, and will continually be checking for the if statement to be true. To fix this, I was wondering if there was a way for it to run in the background, and run concurrently with other operations.

Thank you

Comment: Check it periodically, not continuously.

Comment: Yes, there is a way but it probably shouldn't be done this way as such infinite loop will slow down your program considerably consuming any spare CPU resources. Make this check whenever it actually might be <=0, i.e when you reduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it concurrently: Create a main loop, register various tasks with the loop. Every time around the loop the tasks will run.